# IBM Worklight - Icon is not displayed sharply

Tags: android, image, ibm-mobilefirst

I've designed an app with side bar menu icons.

Each icon in 50 x 50 in size. But when used in the app it does not display as sharp, instead it looks pixelated.

A snapshot of samsung tab2 7inch tab is attached:
[image]

Comment: **Edit the question** with the CSS and HTML snippets used for the icon in your application. Also this screen shot looks like it has been magnified... please add an un-magnified image.

Comment: @Idan Adar: This is the screen-shot taken from samsung tab7: not magnified image. the screen-shot is 600 x 1024 size: 
I've cropped as it is one section for query.

Plz acknowledge.

Comment: Thanks, but you did not answer all of my questions.

Comment: I've added the snippet with in the question. Plz check.

Comment: You did not... Anyway, this seems to be app-level; can you create a small test case Worklight project, export it and upload to Dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

Open AndroidManifest.xml in the generated android project.  On the Manifest tab, under Manifest Extras, select Supports Screens, and on the right set Large screens to true.

Comment: That was so supportive: Thanks Man :-)